# Examples of "risk-averse" loss functions

Tags: references, loss-functions, decision-theory

Could you give me some examples and/or references on "risk-averse" loss functions (i.e. penalizing the underestimates more then the overestimates)?

Comment: Do you mean like the loss function addressed at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251600?

Answer (score 5):

[Bayesian Methods for Hackers](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/blob/master/Chapter5_LossFunctions/Ch5_LossFunctions_PyMC3.ipynb) has a pretty informative chapter on loss functions and touches on this. They provide python function below as an example of a loss function that penalizes overestimates more heavily:

```
def stock_loss(true_return, yhat, alpha = 100.):
    if true_return * yhat < 0:
        #opposite signs, not good
        return alpha*yhat**2 - np.sign(true_return)*yhat \
                        + abs(true_return) 
    else:
        return abs(true_return - yhat)
```

Note: you don't need to go full bayesian for this chapter to be relevant