# Different error weighting for positive and negative residuals for OLS?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, weighted-regression

For OLS-estimators in multivariate regression analysis, it logically doesn't matter whether an error is positive or negative. I was wondering if in some situations it might make sense to weight a positive error less than a negative error (or maybe the other way around). So something like a intentionally optimistic/pessimistic estimation. So I tried to develop something like this myself, but since I'm not a mathematician or statistician, I didn't quite manage it and can't judge very well if something like this really makes sense, or maybe already exists. This is what i got so far:

Instead of the error being
\begin{equation}
SQR_1(\beta) = ||y-X\beta||^2
\end{equation}
I was thinking of something like the function:
\begin{equation}
f(x) = ax^2\cdot s(x) + bx^2\cdot s(-x)
\end{equation}
where:
\begin{equation}
s(x) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot( sgn(x)+1)
\end{equation}
and $a$ and $b$ are parameters weighting the positive/negative errors. $f(x)$ with for example $a=0.2$ and $b=1$ looks like this:

[image]
Instead of $SQR_1$ we can now define:
\begin{equation}
SQR_2(\beta) = f(y-X\beta)
\end{equation}

I know that I now have to solve $\frac{\partial f(y-X\beta)}{\partial \beta} = 0$ for $\beta$. And at this point, I'm not getting any further. And even if I solve this equation, wouldn't there be the next problem to prove that the extrema is a minima because the second derivative of my function is not defined for $x=0$?

So my questions: Do you know how to solve this equation? Do you think that anything I was doing here was useful? Does something like this already exist?

---

<sub>b8d6fffbe062810e1ed8812074bdafedf24b72bf24b8418d7787a85e41f8a0d0</sub>

Comment: Yes, this makes sense.  Such a weighting is routinely done in [quantile regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251600).  Note that global minima can occur where the second derivative (or even the derivative itself) is undefined: that's not an inherent problem.  Checking the second derivative is merely a tool to use in some cases.  For your loss functions, which are globally strictly convex, there is no problem at all: there will be a unique local minimum and it therefore is the global minimum.