# Should we use the absolute value of errors in quantile regression loss function?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, quantiles

I am trying to use quantile regression loss function. Most of the implementations I see [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/quantile-regression-from-linear-models-to-trees-to-deep-learning-af3738b527c3), [here](https://medium.com/the-artificial-impostor/quantile-regression-part-2-6fdbc26b2629), and [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/38035) are using the error directly:

```
error = pred - labels
loss = max(q*error, (1-q)*error)
```

However, I think we should use the absolute value of the error

```
error = abs(pred - labels)
```

Practically, I have tried using non-absolute value, and the training doesn't converge, nevgative values of losses continue to decrease. I am wondering if using the absolute value in the quantile loss makes sense.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251600.