# Leibniz's Rule for integrals with infinity in the bounds - FOC quantile regression

Tags: expected-value, quantile-regression

Hi I came across one application of Leibniz's rule in quantile regression:

$$ \frac{\partial E[\rho_\tau(y-c)]}{\partial c} = \frac{\partial}{\partial c} \left[(1-\tau) \int_{-\infty}^{c}(c-y) f_Y(y) \,dy \, + \tau \int_{c}^{\infty} (y-c) f_Y(y) dy \right]$$ where I am now a little confused as to which values to use for $ a'({\theta}), b'(\theta)$ in the Leibniz rule definition $F(\theta) = \int_{a(\theta)}^{b(\theta)} f(\theta, x) dx$ and $$ \frac{d}{d\theta} F(\theta) = f(\theta, b(\theta))b'(\theta) - f(\theta, a(\theta))a'(\theta) + \int_{a(\theta)}^{b(\theta)} \frac{\partial f(\theta, x)}{\partial \theta} dx$$.

Since now, my $a(\theta) = -\infty$, naively you get $\frac{d}{dc}(-\infty) = 0$ which leads to the correct result if used for all infinite values, but doesn't feel quite right. Is this the way to go, or should one instead use a distributional argument when plugging in $\infty$ into $f_Y(y)$ as a density?

The answer at [Quantile regression: Loss function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251600/quantile-regression-loss-function) unfortunately doesn't specify the first order condition that I'm interested in.

Thank you guys!

Comment: To make your naive approach rigorous, use the (Riemann integral) definition of an improper integral: take limits.  You will need to justify interchanging the limiting and differentiation operations.  Once you do, you will be differentiating a *finite* (but still constant) upper limit.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! That makes a lot of sense. I like this argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You don't need any advanced differentiation rules or limiting arguments: the basics will suffice.**  These are the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, the sum rule of differentiation, and the Chain Rule.

---

Let $$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f_Y(y)\,\mathrm{d}y.$$ The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tells us $F$ is differentiable with derivative $$F^\prime(x) = f_Y(x).$$  Similarly, the function $$G(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x yf_Y(y)\,\mathrm{d}y$$ (assuming it converges) is differentiable with derivative $$G^\prime(x) = xf_Y(x).$$

(If you are familiar with this theorem applied only to *finite* intervals, write $$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^0 f_Y(y)\,\mathrm{d}y +  \int_0^x f_Y(y)\,\mathrm{d}y,$$
notice that the first term is a constant, and apply the sum rule of differentiation.  Use the same method to find $G^\prime.$)

For convenience, write $G(\infty)=\lim_{x\to\infty}G(x)$ (which we assume exists and is finite) and $F(\infty) = \lim_{y\to\infty} F(x) = 1.$

Define the function $g:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}$ as

$$\begin{aligned}
g(a,b,c,d) &= (1-\tau) \int_{-\infty}^{a}(b-y) f_Y(y) \,\mathrm{d}y \, + \tau \int_{c}^{\infty} (y-d) f_Y(y) \mathrm{d}y \\
 &= (1-\tau) \left[bF(a) - G(a)\right] + \tau \left[G(\infty)-G(c) - d(F(\infty)-F(c))\right].
\end{aligned}$$

By virtue of the preceding results, $g$ is differentiable with derivative

$$\begin{aligned}Dg(a,b,c,d) &= \left(\frac{\partial  g}{\partial a},\frac{\partial  g}{\partial b},\frac{\partial  g}{\partial c},\frac{\partial  g}{\partial d}\right)(a,b,c,d)\\
& = ((1-\tau)\left[b f_Y(a)-a f_Y(a)\right],\ (1-\tau) F(a),\\
&\quad\quad\quad \tau \left[d f_Y(c)- c f_Y(c)\right],\ -\tau (1-F(c))).
\end{aligned}$$

Let $\iota:\mathbb R \to \mathbb{R}^4$ be the function

$$\iota(c) = (c,c,c,c).$$

Its derivative is (obviously) the constant vector $D\iota(c)=(1,1,1,1)^\prime.$  But because

$$E\left[\rho_t(y-c)\right]  = g(c,c,c,c) = g(\iota(c)) = (g \circ \iota)(c) ,$$

the (multivariate) Chain Rule yields

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\mathrm{d}E\left[\rho_t(y-c)\right]}{\mathrm{d}c} &= (Dg)(\iota(c)) \circ D\iota(c)\\
&=(1-\tau)\left[c f_Y(c)-c f_Y(c) + F(c)\right] + \\
& \quad\quad\tau \left[c f_Y(c)- c f_Y(c) - (1-F(c)\right]\\
&= F(c) - \tau.
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 1):

There's a better way of solving your initial expression using integration by parts.  We'll work through the derivation for the first term in brackets on the r.h.s. of your initial formula.

First,

$${\partial \over \partial c}\int_{-\infty}^c(c-y)f(y)dy = {\partial \over \partial c}\int_{-\infty}^c cf(y)dy -{\partial \over \partial c}\int_{-\infty}^cyf(y)dy $$

The second term on the r.h.s. evidently equals $-cf(c)$.  The first term can be handled via integration by parts, which we briefly review:

$${\partial fg \over \partial x} = g {\partial f \over \partial x} + f{\partial g \over \partial x}$$

Identifying $f$ in the above with $c$ and $g$ with $\int_{-\infty}^c f(y)dy$ allows us to derive:

$${\partial \over \partial c}c\int_{-\infty}^c f(y)dy = F(c)+cf(c)$$

Combining the expressions for the two terms leaves us with:

$${\partial \over \partial c}\int_{-\infty}^c(c-y)f(y)dy = F(c)$$

A similar application of integration by parts to the second term in brackets allows us to conclude that:

$${\partial \over \partial c}\int_c^{-\infty}(y-c)f(y)dy = - (1 -F(c))$$

and the final expression is:

$$\frac{\partial E[\rho_\tau(y-c)]}{\partial c} = (1-\tau)F(c) - \tau (1-F(c))$$

which a small amount of algebra reveals will equal $0$ for $F(c) = \tau$, or, $c = F^{-1}(\tau)$.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative proof! I would have liked to understand Leibniz's rule in more detail in this particular example, specifically the infinite bounds. That's why I didn't mark it as an answer. But @whuber's comment above was really helpful for that