# Minimizing Expectation

Tags: self-study, expected-value, derivative

I am not entirely sure how the derivative follows from the preceding line in this example.

> $f(x)$ is a PDF. You are supposed to set the derivative to 0 as the expectation needs to be minimised.

Could someone please explain a bit?

$$
C_t(X) = 
\begin{cases}
c(t-X), & \text{if }\  X \le t \\
k(X-t), & \text{if }\  X \ge t 
\end{cases}
$$

$$
E[C_t(X)] = ct\int_0^tf(x)dx \ -c\int_0^txf(x)dx \ +k\int_t^\infty xf(x)dx \ -kt\int_t^\infty f(x)dx\
$$

$$
\cfrac {d}{dt}E[C_t(X)] = ctf(t) \ + cF(t) \ -ctf(t) \ -ktf(t) \ +ktf(t) \ -  k[1-F(t)]
$$

I have only managed to get the first half of the derivative so far.

$$
ct\int_0^tf(x)dx = ctF(t) \ - \ ctF(0)
$$

Since the function is a CDF, it evaluates to 0 at 0 for this distribution. So by differentiating and using the product rule we get:

$$
\cfrac{d}{dt}ctF(t)=ctf(t) +cF(t)
$$

For the next part:
$$
-c \int_0^t xf(x)dx = -c[xF(x)|_0^t \ - \ \int_0^tF(x)]
$$
The derivative will be:
$$
-c[tf(t)+F(t)-F(t)] \ = \ -ctf(t)
$$

Im not sure how to proceed from here, since the upper limit is infinite for the next two integrals. I get stuck when I have to evaluate the function after using integration by parts because of the upper limit.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: An equivalent question is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251600, so that thread might help you.  In the present case, all you need is the sum rule of differentiation, integration by parts, and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: You have to differentiate $\int_0^t g(x)\,\text dx$ as a function of $t$, see eg https://math.stackexchange.com/a/781433/14893.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Apologies for that. I did indeed try to solve it myself, and was unable to complete the answer. It is not actually classwork.

Comment: Thank you for the other answers. I did check, but I'm afraid I still don't get how to finish my problem.

Comment: If the infinite upper limit bothers you, you may either (a) negate the variable of integration, thereby making it the lower limit; or (b) express the integral as a sum of a part with a finite upper limit and the rest--because the rest is a constant, it will disappear when you differentiate.  For more help on differentiating, please post your questions on [math.se].