# Show that, for any real numbers a and b such that m ≤ a ≤ b or m ≥ a ≥ b, E|Y − a| ≤ E|Y − b| ,where Y be a random variable with finite expectation

Tags: self-study, random-variable, expected-value, median, mean-absolute-deviation

Let $Y$ be a random variable with finite expectation, and $m$ be a median
of $Y;$ i.e., $P(Y \le m) \ge 1/2$ and $P(Y \ge m) \ge 1/2.$ Show that, for
any real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $m\le a \le b$ or $m \ge a \ge b,$
$E|Y − a| \le E|Y − b|.$

It is known than the mean absolute deviation is minimum about the median. If $m$ is the median then for $m\le a \le b$ or $m \ge a \ge b,$ $a$ is closer to $m$ than $b.$ So, the expected absolute deviation for $a$ will be less than $b.$ The inequality is intuitively clear to me. *Please prove it mathematically.*

Comment: The first paragraph looks like a homework/self-study question. What are you quoting there?

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, actually it is from a previous year question of an entrance examination.

Comment: Is $E|Y-a|$ shorthand for $E[|Y-a|]$?

Comment: @Acccumulation Yes.

Comment: Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info, add the tag and adjust the post in accordance.

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, I just added the self-study tag.

Comment: Thanks, though ideally some of the other things it asks you to do should also have been undertaken - make a good faith attempt, ask about specific problems encountered in attempting it, identify the source of the question in the post. I get why you did not in this case, but please consider those things  for your next post that merits the tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Intuition

As explained at [Expectation of a function of a random variable from CDF](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222478), an integration by parts shows that when a random variable $X$ has a (cumulative) distribution function $F,$ the expectation of $|X-a|$ is the sum of the shaded areas shown:

[image: Figure]

The left hand region is the area under $F$ to the left of $a$ while the right hand region is the area *above* $F$ to the right of $a:$ that is, it's the area under $1-F$ to the right of $a.$  *This is an extremely useful picture to have in mind when thinking about expectations.  It can make seemingly complicated relationships intuitively obvious.*

The height of $F$ is at least $1/2$ at the median $m,$ as shown by the dotted lines.

When $a \ge m$ is increased to $b,$ these areas change: the left hand area grows while the right hand area shrinks.  The resulting region is shown here in blue.

[image: Figure 2]

The old area was $I+II+IV$ while the new one is $II + III + IV.$  Their difference therefore is $III - I.$ (This is the integral of $F - (1 - F) = 1 - 2F$ between $a$ and $b.$)  Because $III$ includes the entire rectangle between $a$ and $b$ below the height $1/2$ and $I$ lies within the rectangle between $a$ and $b$ above the height $1/2,$ the difference $III - I$ cannot be negative (and actually is positive in the figure).  Thus, *as $a\ge m$ increases, the expectation of $|X-a|$ cannot shrink -- it can only grow.*

A similar geometric argument can be used to analyze any quantile, not just the median, by means of a suitable weighting of the upper and lower areas.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/252043/919 for some analysis of this.

#### Formal Solution

Fix an arbitrary (but finite) $b \gt m,$ suppose $a$ is any number for which $m \le a \le b,$ and consider the difference

$$h(a) = E\left[|Y-b| - |Y-a|\right] = E\left[|Y-b|\right] - E\left[|Y-a|\right].$$

We aim to show $h(a) \ge 0.$  We will do this by computing the expectation and finding a simple lower bound for it.  The only technique we need is a straightforward integration by parts.

Writing $F$ for the distribution of $Y$ and integrating in the sense of Lebesgue-Stieltjes, **compute this expectation by breaking the integral into three regions** bounded by $a$ and $b$ so that the absolute values can be expressed more simply within each region (look closely at how the signs in the integrands vary in the third line):

$$\begin{aligned}
h(a) &= \int \left(|x-b| - |x-a|\right)\,\mathrm{d}F(x) \\
&= \left(\int_{-\infty}^a + \int_a^b + \int_b^\infty\right) \left(|x-b| - |x-a|\right)\,\mathrm{d}F(x) \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^a(b-x)-(a-x)\,\mathrm{d}F(x)  + \int_a^b(b-x)-(x-a) \,\mathrm{d}F(x) \\&\quad+ \int_b^\infty(x-b)-(x-a)\,\mathrm{d}F(x) \\
&= (b-a)\int_{-\infty}^a\,\mathrm{d}F(x)  + \int_a^b(a+b-2x) \,\mathrm{d}F(x) + (a-b)\int_b^\infty\,\mathrm{d}F(x). \\
\end{aligned}$$

**Evaluate the middle integral by parts:**

$$\begin{aligned}
\int_a^b(a+b-2x) \,\mathrm{d}F(x) &= (a+b-2x)F(x)\bigg|^b_a + 2\int_a^b F(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&= (a-b)F(b) - (b-a)F(a)+ 2\int_a^b F(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= (a-b)(F(b) + F(a))+ 2\int_a^b F(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.
\end{aligned}$$

Plug this into the previous expression for $h(a)$ and note that **because $a \ge m,$ $F(x) \ge 1/2$ throughout this integral**:

$$\begin{aligned}
h(a) & = (b-a)F(a) + \left[(a-b)(F(b)+F(a)) + 2\int_a^b F(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right] + (a-b)(1 - F(b)) \\
&= a-b + 2\int_a^b F(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&= 2\int_a^b \left(F(x) - \frac{1}{2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&\ge 2\int_a^b \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&=0,
\end{aligned}$$

*QED.*

The demonstration for the other case $b \le a \le m$ follows by applying this result to the random variable $-Y$ and the values $-m\le-a\le-b$ (because $-m$ is a median of $-Y.$)

Comment: +1 The second chart is more helpful as an aid to understanding than the formal solution.

Comment: @Henry Agreed.  But it takes more effort to create :-(.