# Question regarding the Bayes estimator of a parameter $\theta$ which has a continuous distribution

Tags: self-study, bayesian, inference, hierarchical-bayesian, variational-bayes

Let $c > 0$ and
\begin{equation}
 L(\theta,a)=\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    c|\theta-a|, & \text{if}\ \theta < a \\
    |\theta-a|, & \text{if}\ \theta \ge a \quad.
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
We assume here that $\theta$ has a continuous distribution. How do I show that the Bayes estimator of $\theta$ is the $\frac{1}{1+c}$th quantile of the posterior distribution of $\theta$?

Can anyone please give me any hints regarding this? Thanks.

Comment: Please explain what $L$ and $a$ are intended to represent.  Likelihood?  If $L$ is loss, then your question is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251600 (and in several other threads).

Comment: The solution is found in most textbooks, incl. mine.

Comment: @Xi'an can you please provide me the name of your testbook? Thanks!